# Reading from plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, plist

I'm having problem reading from a plist file
I have the Settings.plist file saved in my project (tried both in and out of the Resources folder)
And none of the method google and stackOverFlow has to offered worked. I have no idea what I'm missing.
the code is:

```
    NSString *pListPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Settings" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *settings = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pListPath] retain];
    BOOL touch = [[settings objectForKey:@"Touch"] boolValue];
    NSLog(@"%@",touch ? @"TOUCH IS YES" : @"TOUCH IS NO");
```

I've tried many different methods of getting the *plistPath, NSBundle, just a string with the file name. also tried NSMutabelDictionary, regulat NSDictionary, NSArray, NSMutableArray

Nothing seems to work.
Tried setting the plist first line into a Root dictionary, still no luck..

Any help would be apreciated..
Settings.plist has a single value Touch and its key is YES
Thanks alot!

EDIT:
Here's the plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Root</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Touch</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: What is the value of `settings` after `initWithContentsOfFile:` returns?  Also, edit your question and paste in the contents of the `Settings.plist` file.

Comment: How to tell the value of settings it self?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your plist contains a top-level dictionary with one key, “`Root`”.  The value for that key is another dictionary with one key, “`Touch`”.

Try this:

```
BOOL touch = [[[settings objectForKey:@"Root"] objectForKey:@"Touch"] boolValue];
```

or this (slightly slower):

```
BOOL touch = [[settings valueForKeyPath:@"Root.Touch"] boolValue];
```

Comment: They both do the same thing.  The second is easier to write but runs slower.